# Is it possbile to write an Hybrid app for iOS bluetooth (html5/js/css3 + Xcode)?

Tags: android, ios, html, hybrid

I am new to app development and this is my first post to stack. Thank you for reading my question :)

I am going to write an App on Android and iOS via bluetooth to control some hardware, so start to do research on Cross-Platform tools / IDE, such as phonegap / titanium / Intel XDK / Mosync(even Mosync  C++ IDE) etc.. , none of them support iOS bluetooth, it seems the only way to use bluetooth on iOS is using Xcode, am I right?

the question is can I use phonegap / Intel XDK (html 5) to write the app UI and some basic control, and convert the code to Xcode then continue to write the bluetooth module in Xcode, I am no idea of this... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use the [Bluetooth Serial plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/366) with PhoneGap which might do what you want? I haven't tried it myself.